# .HTACCESS help masking a URL

Tags: .htaccess

My current URL is

http://domain.com/directory/page.php

I would like the page to be accessed and addressbar to keep it as

http://domain.com/page

is this possible with htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable mod_rewrite.  Then, you can put something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/page$ /directory/page.php [L]
```

If you want to do this for all of the php scripts in /directory/, you could do this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /directory/$1.php [L]
```